# How to update near by TD text box value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, angularjs

I am working on shopping cart application. There I need to update my product screens based on users previous orders which stored as local JSON. I am building my product screen from server returned JSON.

Now I want to update the quantity automatically for every product returned from server comparing with local JSON of previous orders.

For example product screen have item 'SNICKERS' and previous order also have same item with quantity i need to fill those quantity value inside textbox of 'SNICKERS' row TD in table. Please refer my attached image.

Like wise I need to update all quantity values if previous order items & place order screen items get matched.  I am doing matching with product code, I done with that, but I do not know how to update the quantity value in textbox.

Local JSON:

```js
Object {order_id: "9ec3bd80-91fc-0138-c8e0-0cc47ac946e0", product_code: "1000", quantity: 1, …}
```

Json From Server

```js
Object {macs_menu_id: "1047-2000000365", header_text: null, total_price: "1.68", …}
4:Object {macs_menu_id: "1047-2000000365", header_text: null, total_price: "1.04", …}
header_text:null
header_text:null
indigent_kit:0
macs_menu_id:"1047-2000000365"
menu_prod_cat:"CNDY"
product_code:"1000"
product_desc:"SNICKERS - K"
quan_limit:0
sort_order:910
total_price:"1.68"}
```

My code to compare both json product code is below

```
for (const x in prev_orders) {
              for (const y in response.payload.filter(d => d.product_code != null && d.macs_menu_id === this.InmateMacMenu).sort((a, b) => a.sort_order - b.sort_order)) {
                if (prev_orders[x].product_code === response.payload[y].product_code) {
                  if ($('.mat-elevation-z8 td:contains("' + prev_orders[x].product_code + '")')) {
                    // if product code matched
                    console.log('product code matched ' + response.payload[y].product_code);                
                    $('.mat-elevation-z8 td:contains("' + prev_orders[x].product_code + '")').closest('td').find('input').val(prev_orders[x].quantity);
                  }
                } else {
                  console.log('not matched');
                }
              }
            }
```

I am getting product code match message in console. Now I need to update quantity in textbox. Can anyone help me to do this? Thanks

Place Order Screen

[image]

Console Msg

[image]

And my HTML code

```html
    <table id="products" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
              <ng-container matColumnDef="menu_prod_cat">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 35px;"> Category </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data; let i = index" [attr.rowspan]="getRowSpan('menu_prod_cat', i)" [style.display]="getRowSpan('menu_prod_cat', i) ? '' : 'none'"> {{data.menu_prod_cat }}</td>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container matColumnDef="product_code">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Code </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data" (click)="get_image_binary(data)" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == data.product_code}"> {{data.product_code}} </td>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container matColumnDef="product_desc">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Description </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == data.product_code}" (click)="get_image_binary(data)"> {{data.product_desc }} </td>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container matColumnDef="total_price">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Price </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data" (click)="get_image_binary(data)" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == data.product_code}">
                      {{data.total_price | currency}} </td>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container matColumnDef="quan_limit">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 20px;">Quantity Limit </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data" (click)="get_image_binary(data)" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == data.product_code}">
                      {{data.quan_limit }} </td>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container matColumnDef="Quantity">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 35px;"> Quantity </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data; let i = index" (click)="get_image_binary(data)" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == data.product_code}">
                    <!-- <ng-numeric-input [layout]="'tel'" [class]="'form-control'"  maxlength={{data.quan_limit}}  [id]="'txtqty{i}'" [placeholder]="'0'"  [(ngModel)]="data.quantity" (keyup)="quantityModelChange($event,data)" [entertext]="'Next'"></ng-numeric-input> -->
                     <input type="number" id=txtqty{{i}} pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" min="1" max={{data.quan_limit}} [(ngModel)]="data.quantity" (keyup)="quantityModelChange($event,data)" class="Col-tdinput">
                      <!-- <input type="number" min="1" max={{data.quan_limit}} (ngModel)="data.quantity" class="Col-tdinput" (keyup)="quantityKeypress($event,data)" pattern="[0-9]*">
                      (ngModelChange)="quantityModelChange($event,data)"
                      -->
                  </td>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container matColumnDef="Total">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Total </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data" (click)="get_image_binary(data)" [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == data.product_code}">
                      <p *ngIf="data.quantity > 0">{{data.total_price * data.quantity | currency}}</p>
                  </td>
              </ng-container>
              <ng-container matColumnDef="Action">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let data" (click)="get_image_binary(data)">
                      <button class="Col-Cartbtn" (click)="IncermentProduct(data)">+</button>
                      <button class="Col-Cartbtn" [disabled]="data.quantity==0" (click)="DecrementProduct(data)">-</button>
                  </td>
              </ng-container>
              <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
              <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: Could you please share html code?

Comment: sure check my question i will add html code there

Comment: Do you want this in Angular or jQuery?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use jQuery? Seems like you project is based on AngularJS

Comment: angular or jQuery anything is okay if you guys provide me solution

Comment: in angulr i can use ngif key, but i cant pass two dataset in ngif. or anyway to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i found  answer myself. its simple one i just assigning the local json quantity value to server json quantity.

because i bind my textboxes by using data.quantity attribute, so when i compare the product code at that time i assigning the values. check my attahced code.  thanks for your comments

```js
for (const x in prev_orders) {
          // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
          for (const y in response.payload.filter(d => d.product_code != null && d.macs_menu_id === this.InmateMacMenu).sort((a, b) => a.sort_order - b.sort_order)) {
            if (prev_orders[x].product_code === response.payload[y].product_code) {
              // tslint:disable-next-line:only-arrow-functions
              $('tr').each(function() {
                if ($('td:contains("' + prev_orders[x].product_code + '")')) {
                  // if product code matched
                  response.payload[y].quantity = prev_orders[x].quantity;
                  self.addProductToCart(response.payload[y], response.payload[y].quantity);
                }
              });
            } else {
              console.log('not matched');
            }
          }
        }
```